# Не могу сгенерировать Aztec code на русском языке python

Tags: python, qrcode

подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли в aztec-код зашифровать предложения на русском языке? Пытался сделать через библиотеку aztec_code_generator, но у меня не получилось.

Comment: Код и примеры данных (входных и выходных) должны быть приведены прямо в вопросе

Comment: Судя по исходному коду той библиотеки там только латиница предусмотрена, да https://github.com/delimitry/aztec_code_generator/blob/master/aztec_code_generator.py